# How to control two different projects in the same local directory (separate remote repo)

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I have a problem using git.

I know there are a lot of similar questions out there, but it gets so confusing as i search and read more.

**Could anyone read below case and tell me if this case can also be solved by using submodules / subtrees?**

I have a folder name `workspace`. It has two different projects like below.

```
workspace --- project one
          --- project two
```

So far, I've been working on only `project one`, and i have had no problem committing and pushing to my github repo. Now, it becomes a problem as i want to commit and push the `project two` to different remote repo. I found out `.git file` is the issue. It gets conflict if i want to control two different repos in the same directory.

**Could anyone guide me how to solve this ?**

Using submodules or subtree is the right way to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't put two repositories in the same directory. One repository per directory. If you want two repositories, you need two directories.

Comment: @GregHewgill So, what you're saying is there is no solution for this? I guess the best thing I can do is to go inside the `project two` folder and control it, right?

Comment: if you have .git folder seperate in each project you can put that two folders in one folder.